# "До тысячИ пятисот" или "до тысячА пятисот"?

Tags: числительные

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: *до тысяч**и** пятисот* или *до тысяч**а** пятисот?*
Логика подсказывает, что первый вариант верный, но лучше всё же уточнить. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тысяча пятьсот (1500) — это составное (то есть состоящее из нескольких слов) количественное числительное, в нем склоняется каждое слово.
Предлог "до" — это предлог родительного падежа (кого? чего?).
Правильно: *до тысяч**и** пятисот*.

― Да, но зато мы увеличиваем боевой комплект снарядов полевой артиллерии **до тысячи пятисот** выстрелов на орудие и по двести запасных, ― не без гордости утешал меня мой собеседник. [А. А. Игнатьев. Пятьдесят лет в строю. Кн. 3 (1947-1953)]

«Противник численностью **около тысячи пятисот** человек, при трех орудиях, повел наступление на деревню Каурово, после суточного ураганного боя противник вынужден был отступить с большими потерями». [Сергей Залыгин. Соленая Падь (1967)]

[Как правильно употреблять числительные?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/61-rubric-92)
[Предлоги падежей в русском языке](https://izamorfix.ru/rus/morfologiya/padeji_suschestvit.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Прекрасный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Правильно вам подсказывает интуиция, склоняются оба слова.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!